# pause and resume listeners not working in phonegap on iOS4.3 and iOS 5

Tags: iphone, ios, cordova

I was making a native app in iPhone4 with iOS 4.3

in my Body onLoad i m adding

```
document.addEventListener("pause", Game.prototype.pauseListener.bind(this), false);
document.addEventListener("resume", Game.prototype.resumeListener.bind(this), false);
```

and in that same file i m writing a function

```
Game.prototype.resumeListener= function()
{

    console.log("in resumeListener");
    this.PauseGame(false);
}

Game.prototype.pauseListener= function()
{
        this.PauseGame(true);

}
```

this code is working perfectly fine in Android and when i manually minimise the app, but when the application is interrupted by a voice incoming call the application dont pause.

Basically Pause and Resume event are not fired.

I m using Phonegap1.4.1

Answer (score 1):

I believe your event listeners are not being established because you are using `Object.bind()` on the handler functions, and `.bind()` is not available in the iOS WebKit widget.  (This is surpising because `.bind()` **is** available in the desktop WebKit (Chrome and Safari) versions.)

The easy solution is to add a polyfill definition for Object.bind(). I use the one from the [MDN bind documentation page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind), and haven't had any problems with it.

Comment: I have overwrite the bind method for my js files and bind is as good as apply in pure js.
And it is working fine at other places in iOS.

Answer (score 0):

sorry but i cant make a comment yet ;)

have you checked the two other events (active and resign only for ios)? more information: http://shazronatadobe.wordpress.com/2012/03/14/apache-cordova-lifecycle-events-in-ios-4-versus-ios-5/

or see iOS Quirks in the documentation: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.6.1/cordova_events_events.md.html#pause

Comment: even this is not working .....it is working on in case of lock button but not in case of call.

Comment: why do you use **bind(this)**... isnt it already global scope?

Comment: no it is not a global function....it is just a local function of that game.js file .....

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your listeners in the deviceready instead of in the onLoad.
Just like here for example

```
function onLoad() {
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
}

function onDeviceReady() {
    document.addEventListener("pause", onPause, false);
}

function onPause() {
}
```

Hope it helps :)